# Application that will tell the DNS server for my PC and network

Tags: dns

What application can determine the best DNS server for my PC or network?

Comment: What do you mean by `best`?

Comment: best meaning, its most likely the most compatible. The dns server which matches the pc and the network

Comment: there is no such thing as "the best DNS server". Use the one from your ISP or OpenDNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the [nameserver-benchmark](http://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm) and see what's `best` for you:

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/12/04/dns-server-benchmark-namebench/

Comment: DNSBenchmark got 2 viruses detected by virustotal.com but rated as `Good ware` http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=0baf546d6ac9fd853b11cba89d3f314ca3ff0ca791224aa0753f0441a396dbe7-1304861562

Comment: @Nam Gi VU: don't know why you bring up "dnsbenchmark", never said anything about "dnsbenchmark". i talked about "namesaver-benchmark" ...

Answer (score 1):

[DNS Benchmark](https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm) will tell you which is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

as for high performance: running your own nameserver will always be the best DNS server for your working set.